# Invalid length parameter passed to LEFT or SUBSTRING - But neither function used in query

Tags: sql

This query has been used successfully before but now throws this error and I can't seem to avoid it.  The query runs for around half it's usual circa 20 min runtime and then fails with this error:

Msg 537, Level 16, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Query:

```
USE [INDEXES]
GO
            SELECT DISTINCT
                   [ADDRESS]
                  ,[POSTCODE]
                  ,[POSTCODE DISTRICT]
                  ,[LKP_FULL_FULL_PC]
                  ,[LKP_FULL_PCS]
                  ,[LKP_NO_ST_FULL_PCS]
            INTO [INDEXES].[dbo].[LR_LOOKUP]
            FROM [PROP_DATA].[dbo].[LR_Standardised_Lookups]
            WHERE LEN(POSTCODE) > 0
```

I'm assuming this is a data issue because the query runs for around 10 mins before failing, but I can't fathom what the issue is as there are no column manipulations in the query. It's simply saying if there is a POSTCODE value include it.

Note that I've also tried using:

WHERE p.POSTCODE IS NOT NULL (with AS p on the FROM clause) but gives    me same result.

WHERE DATALENGTH(POSTCODE) - same result

I've seen lots of posts on this error but they all seem to be using string manipulation which results in invalid results on some rows, whereas I am not - it's just a simple match clause here.

UPDATE:  I've tried many functions in the WHERE, then I dropped the WHERE altogether - same error message.

...now I'm really confused, the error makes no sense in context.

Comment: Either one of those columns is a computed column you need to inspect the definition of to find the `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` function, or LR_Standardised_Lookup is a view rather than a table and you need to inspect the definition (ditto).

Comment: LR_Standardised_Lookups is a view but the column isn't computed

Comment: note also that I've tried WHERE DATALENGTH(POSTCODE) too, same result

Answer (score 0):

This might run a little better for you:

```
USE [INDEXES]
GO
SELECT DISTINCT
[ADDRESS],
[POSTCODE],
[POSTCODE DISTRICT],
[LKP_FULL_FULL_PC],
[LKP_FULL_PCS],
[LKP_NO_ST_FULL_PCS]
INTO [INDEXES].[dbo].[LR_LOOKUP]
FROM [PROP_DATA].[dbo].[LR_Standardised_Lookups]
WHERE POSTCODE <> ''
AND POSTCODE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that too yields the same result

Comment: Shoot, I was hoping that would work out for you. For this query, are you needing to copy the results to LR_LOOKUP, because if you just need the results to display, you can take the INTO part out.

Comment: This query actually creates the LR_LOOKUP table in the INDEXES db.  So my process when updating datasources is to update other tables with updated public data, then delete LR_LOOKUP and run this query to recreate it using updated sources.

Currently it is creating the table, albeit an empty one because the query always falls over at the same point

Comment: I can see data in the LR_Standardised_Lookups view but there are millions of rows, I'm currently trying to find a way to search it for bad characters, though is just a VARCHAR so not sure what would make that fall over.

Another factor to consider is that I'm using SQL Express so db size limits apply, but I don't think I'm hitting them